# How to split the page when click on Marker in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, jquery-ui

if i click my marker my window should split in two,where left side should my map locate and right side should show the array content of market?

```
var locations = [
    [
            "clientDigital",
            12.9965541, 80.2559071,
            4,
            "Steven F. Morris",
            "Sandfiddler Pawn Shop",
            "5429 Tidewater Dr.",
            "found"
        ],
        [
            "Aubrica the Mermaid (nee: Aubry Alexis)",
            36.8618, -76.203,
            5,
            "Myke Irving/ Georgia Mason",
            "USAVE Auto Rental",
            "Virginia Auto Rental on Virginia Beach Blvd",
            "found"
        ]
    ]

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    // center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.8857, -76.2599),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br />" + locations[i][4] + "<br />" + locations[i][5] + "<br />" + locations[i][6]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }

    })(marker, i));
}
</script>
<div id="map" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hidden div in the html part that you show on a click on a marker, while filling the specific values into the the already prepared divs.

my example won't be on the right side of the map, but this can be done with a little CSS (float: left;).
I havent tried it out yet, but this is how i would do it

```
var locations = [
    [
            "clientDigital",
            12.9965541, 80.2559071,
            4,
            "Steven F. Morris",
            "Sandfiddler Pawn Shop",
            "5429 Tidewater Dr.",
            "found"
        ],
        [
            "Aubrica the Mermaid (nee: Aubry Alexis)",
            36.8618, -76.203,
            5,
            "Myke Irving/ Georgia Mason",
            "USAVE Auto Rental",
            "Virginia Auto Rental on Virginia Beach Blvd",
            "found"
        ]
    ]

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    // center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.8857, -76.2599),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br />" + locations[i][4] + "<br />" + locations[i][5] + "<br />" + locations[i][6]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

            //show singleMarkerValues-div
            $('#singleMarkerValues').show();

            //insert specific values
            $('#singleName').html(locations[i][0]);
            $('#singleLatLng').html(locations[i][1]+', '+locations[i][2]);
            $('#singlePerson').html(locations[i][3]);
            ...
        }

    })(marker, i));
}
</script>


<div id="map"></div>

<div id="singleMarkerValues" style="display: none;">
    <div id="singleName"></div>
    <div id="singleLatLng"></div>
    <div id="singlePerson"></div>
    ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a click listener to your marker that resize the div, call map resize and display the "data" on the right.

The listener shoud look like this

```
 marker.addListener('click', function() {
             map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
              document.getElementById("map").style.width = "50%";
              google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
              document.getElementById("data").style.display = "inline";
              document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = locations.toString();
            });
```

Where map is the map instance and you have a map div and a data div that will contain your array

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rixlabs/q3xh9p8u/2/) for demo.

I didn't format the data.

Hope this helps

Comment: window size has been resized? but i need my page as like https://www.airbnb.co.in/things-to-do/new-york . where if i click my marker it should show the array value.

Comment: So you need to format the informations??? are you using any JS framework?

Comment: ya, need to format the information. by giving simple css(float:left) all the array data has been display in left side . I need to dispay the particular marker array values?

Comment: look at this -> https://jsfiddle.net/rixlabs/q3xh9p8u/4/  updated version of the fiddle. I create the template with strings, absolutely not the best choice.  If you get the locations from a backend you can generate the html there